# How can I correct the horizontal movement of the mouse cursor?

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I use a dock at work once a week. When I use the mouse attached to it and move it to the right horizontally, it moves about 12° clockwise from horizontal. This affects selecting text with the mouse, drag and drop, etc., because the mouse pointer is rarely where I expect it to be. I work remotely the rest of the time, and I don't have this problem with my own mouse.

Can I adjust a setting somewhere in Windows 10 to make horizontal movement of the mouse almost exactly 0° movement of the mouse cursor?